# How to ensure that a document field is unique in ArangoDB Cluster

Tags: database, cluster-computing, arangodb, unique-constraint

I have a 3 nodes Arango Cluster (Community edition).
I created a database with writeConcern=3 and replicationFactor=3 and a collection with shards=3, and replicationFactor=3.
I have a Hash index on a field of that collection with the unique property set to true. However I am still able to create different documents with the same field value.

I would like to know if there is some strategies to ensure uniqueness of a collection field in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section [Indexes On Shards](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/architecture-deployment-modes-cluster-sharding.html#indexes-on-shards) in the Arango docs says the following:

> Unique indexes (hash, skiplist, persistent) on sharded collections are only allowed if the fields used to determine the shard key are also included in the list of attribute paths for the index

The reason behind this is simple - it would be *very* expensive to ensure uniqueness of an attribute `x` if it is not guaranteed that all documents with identical values of `x` are stored on the same node.

Comment: Thank you!
Using a field as shard key and create an index with unique property set to true ensure uniqueness in the cluster for that field values.